# Cannot set headers for Http in Angular 4

Tags: angular, http, header

In login.service.ts, I have a method named getStudent(), in which I set the JWT token as header and access to backend (Spring boot). However, I always receive the message that headers is missing. This is my code:
login.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, HttpModule, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { ConnectionService } from './connection.service';
import { RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';

declare var $: any;
@Injectable()
export class LoginService {
  private loginState = new Subject<any>();
  public headers: any;


  constructor(private http: Http, private connectionLink: ConnectionService, private cookie:CookieService) {
   }

  getStudent(id: string) {
    let options:any = new RequestOptions();
    let headers: any = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.cookie.get('token'));
    options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/getStudentinfoByIDREST/'+id,options)
    .toPromise()
    .then(res =>res.json())
  }
}
```

This is my CorsConfig.java in back-end:

```
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
public class CorsConfig {

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("OPTIONS");
        config.addAllowedMethod("HEAD");
        config.addAllowedMethod("GET");
        config.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
        config.addAllowedMethod("POST");
        config.addAllowedMethod("DELETE");
        config.addAllowedMethod("PATCH");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        // return new CorsFilter(source);
        final FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));
        bean.setOrder(0);
        return bean;
    }

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer mvcConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedMethods("GET", "PUT", "POST", "GET", "OPTIONS");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

I'm sure that my backend work properly because I tested it many times with Postman. Therefore, I assume there's something wrong with my code. Please help me, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like to me a problem of server configuration.

"No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" means the origin from where you make a request (here localhost:4200) is not allow to access your api.

Maybe you can try to use the @CrossOrigin annotation in the api endpoint you request. This annotation allows all origins on the annotated endpoint. This way you will see if this is really a problem with your config or not.

Hope that helps

Comment: What can I do to fix it?

Comment: You should change your server config to allow your api to be requested from your origin. Are your sure your CorsConfig is actually used ?

Comment: I'm not really sure but I don't know how to check it. Is there any way to check?

Comment: I edited my response with a way to check quickly it the problem comes from the server configuration :)

Comment: I use @CrossOrigin annotation already, but the result is still the same.

Comment: Hum, can you go in the devtools, in the network section, and show us the request headers ?

Answer (score -1):

append this into header 
**`headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin' , '*');`** 
because it's error from cors

Comment: This has no affect, `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` needs to be set in backend.

Comment: what error you getting ? can you send me screen short of error

Comment: I'm not the OP, I just commented :)

Comment: Yeah, it actually doesn't work. The error I get (when I use Console of chrome to check) is No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

Comment: I updated my CorsConfig.java in backend, you guys can take a look.

Comment: please add Access-Control-Allow-Origin in header